Can't access back wheel hub - NO BOLTS!
I've recently purchase an old dutch bike that has a coaster brake.
I'm wanting to get inside the back wheels hub to clean it out but I can't work out how to access it. There are no bolts or not a clear way to remove items. I'm not even sure which side I should be trying to access first.
Any ideas welcome? Spent hours trying. Thanks!



Good resource here: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/coaster-brakes.html#:~:text=Single%2Dspeed%20coaster%20brakes%20are,side%20of%20the%20hub%20shell.

That looks like it may be an old Bendix two speed hub?
What does the reaction arm say on it

On your first photo, there's a nut with two notches that you should be able to remove. There are specialized tools that fit those notches, but in the worst case, a hammer and screwdriver should work too.
After removing all the rest from that side, you should be able to pull out the axle from the drive side. Here's a video.
The second photo shows a notch with behind it a ring that retains the sprocket. Pry some pointy tool under that ring to remove.
